# How to stop Bootstrap column from aligning to the bottom of a row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="expandable-input-small" id="input_element" contenteditable="true" data-max-length="100">Test </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn" type="submit" value="click" name="delete_element">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The "delete_element" button I'm trying to make here seems to insist on aligning to the bottom no matter how I try to style it, either by using inline CSS styling or calling bootstrap align methods. I want to have it aligned with the contenteditable element - how do I do this? Is there a bug when you use a button in a col?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/#vertical-alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand how Bootstrap works, that's why your button is aligned to the bottom of the **`row` (!)** no matter what.

*Note: I edited your question title because it's wrong.*

> Wrong: How to stop Bootstrap button from aligning to the bottom of a col?

> Correct: How to stop Bootstrap column from aligning to the bottom of a row?

Because of the class `col`, your button will always be taking full screen width (i.e., 12 columns) no matter what CSS you add. Consequently, it's not the button that causes the problem. It's the column class that causes the problem.

If you want your two elements to be side by side, then:

1. both columns together should not exceed 12 columns and
2. you should not use the class `col` (you can use classes `col-1`, `col-2`, `col-3`, etc.).

In an example below you can see that I used the class `col-1` twice (1 column + 1 column = 2 columns, which is less than 12 columns). I suggest you to read Bootstrap 5 docs about the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/).

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="expandable-input-small" id="input_element" contenteditable="true" data-max-length="100">Test </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button class="btn" type="submit" value="click" name="delete_element">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```